# How do I fix this jquery code that sends a dropdown value to a text field?

Tags: jquery

I thought I had this figured out, but can't get it working correctly:

**All I want is the following**:
onChange of either of these dropdowns take the selected value and add it to the hiddentext field *[in the actual app, these dropdowns are in a fieldset and only one or the other is displayed based on product type selected]*  Simple I know, but I can't see what I am doing wrong.

**Code below and my jsFiddle is here**: http://jsfiddle.net/justmelat/M3hyX/

```
<form method="post" action="">
<fieldset name="projInfo" id="projInfo">
                <legend>Proj Info</legend>
                Hidden Product Field:  <input name="hiddenProdField" id="hiddenProdField" type="text" />
                            </fieldset>

<fieldset name="Group1" id="Group1">
                <legend>Product 1</legend>
                <select name="firstSet"  id="firstSet">
                <option value="0">Select</option>
                <option value="One">One</option>
                <option value="Two">Two</option>
                <option value="Three">Three</option>
            </select>
            </fieldset>
<fieldset name="Group2" id="Group2">
                <legend>Product 2</legend>
                <select name="secondSet"  id="secondSet">
                <option value="0">Select</option>
                <option value="Four">Four</option>
                <option value="Five">Five</option>
                <option value="Six">Six</option>
            </select>
            </fieldset>
<fieldset name="Group3" id="Group3">
                <legend>Product 3</legend>
                <select name="thirdSet"  id="thirdSet">
                <option value="0">Select</option>
                <option value="Seven">Seven</option>
                <option value="Eight">Eight</option>
                <option value="Nine">Nine</option>
            </select>
            </fieldset>
</form>​

$(document).ready(function() {
        $("select#firstSet, select#secondSet, select#thirdSet").change(function(){
            var prodType = "";
            $("select#firstSet, select#secondSet, select#thirdSet option:selected");
            prodType = $(this).text();
          $("#hiddenProdField").text(prodType);
        })
        .trigger('change');
    });
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/M3hyX/14/

Comment: Guest - yours worked as well, thank you!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('fieldset select').change(function() {
 $('input#hiddenProdField').val(this.value);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/M3hyX/13/)

Comment: Hi theCodeParadox - this is not working, it doesn't pop the textfield [#hiddenProdField].  I created a fiddle here trying it:http://jsfiddle.net/justmelat/zs2Js/

Answer (score 3):

You've mistaken the `text()` function and the `val()` function. See http://jsfiddle.net/M3hyX/5/

```
    $("#firstSet, #secondSet, #thirdSet").change(function(){
        $("#hiddenProdField").val($(this).val());
    })
    .trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `$("#hiddenProdField").text(prodType);` should be `$("#hiddenProdField").val(prodType);`